# Выделить всю таблицу при нажатии на чекбокс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица. У каждого `tr` есть чекбокс, и кнопки редактирования и удаления. Так же, в хедере таблицы есть чекбокс. При нажатии на чекбокс который в хедере, выделилась вся таблица (все чекбоксы). Сам вопрос в том, есть ли какой то плагин, который предоставляет этот функционал?

Comment: Это простые вещи, чтобы подключать плагин: https://jsfiddle.net/0e163u78/ (один из вариантов, который не претендует на «Лучший»).

Comment: @RomanGrinyov спасибо. Теперь есть от чего отталкиваться)